# Expanding on Arduinos definition of a capacitor

Tags: arduino, capacitor, circuit-protection

This oversimplified explanation is somewhat confusing and I haven't been able to fully understand what they are trying to say. They already seem to be talking about AC and Voltage regulation.

Update: *The particular problem with this definition in an introductory textbook for the Arduino is that it doesn't clarifies if they are referring to AC or DC current or whether they are talking about a setup with the cap wired across the power source or in one of the wires.*

[image: Explanation from Arduinos manual]

Comment: (1) [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zyuRcsM0gjI) should should adjust your outlook on basic electronics.  (2) On the web, there is no shortage of introductory articles (with sufficient depth) about capacitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the text sums them up quite well. A cap is like a small battery or "charge storage device", and can store and discharge energy. When "empty", electricity flows into them until fully charged, then stops flowing in. When some kind of load is placed across them, they discharge that stored energy into the load.

Caps *oppose instantaneous change of stored charge* - meaning once charged or discharged, or any level between, they like to stay that way. Changing the charge level (voltage) of a cap takes either an energy supply, or energy discharge. This is why they are used to "filter" power to chips and other circuits - they tend to "smooth out" any power glitches since they oppose instantaneous changes in voltage. This is for DC circuits and voltages, and why caps are commonly seen across the power rails (say +5v and ground) of integrated circuits and power supplies - to smooth out any voltage spikes. DC means "direct current", meaning the voltage should be a constant value, such as 5.00v, and not fluctuate over time. The caps wired this way help ensure this is true.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZJTBH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you could "see" the electricity at the unfiltered power point, it would look a lot more "noisy" than after the cap. Many circuits require "clean" DC power in order to work properly, such as this "sensitive load."

As with many concepts in electronics, this concept can be inverted. Since caps "oppose the instantaneous change of voltage", the same idea can be applied to AC, or "alternating current", which are signals which *are* constantly changing. If an AC signal were connected to the previous example, the cap would tend to eliminate anything getting through - so essentially "block" AC, while only allowing DC through:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0SeR8.png)</sup>

Keep in mind this is with the cap wired *across* the power source. But what would happen if the cap were wired only in the +5v wire?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJxtJ7.png)</sup>

If supplied DC in series, the cap will "charge up", then not supply any power to the load, since it itself has "absorbed" all of the voltage difference. So in this sense, it is blocking DC now.

And likewise, if supplied AC, since it resists instantaneous changes, those changes are passed directly to the load. So in this sense, it allows AC, and blocks DC.

These features of capacitors are used heavily in electronics to filter power, amd to couple (and reject) AC signals.

Comment: In the last example, AC passes because it is just charging and then discharging the capacitor creating a relative difference in charge, that is then transmitted distally, right? It is really the first step of the charging process in DC, happening over and over again. So in a sense the first time the capacitor is receiving DC charge the circuit is also seeing that current until the capacitor becomes fully charged. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I still don't understand the examples with "the cap wired across the power source". Can you please explain or point me to a good source to review that setup. Thanks for such a great answer. It was precisely what I was trying to elucidate!

Comment: @BluePython  The source you are looking for: [The Art of Electronics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Electronics) .

Comment: What would be a real world application other than preventing the passage of DC current for a "cap wired across the power source" ?  For the cap in parallel to the resistor it was to smooth out the changes.

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_S-kbHdduB4) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Ua5XrpSUn8) video by mjlorton should explain the details of capacitors. If this is too advanced, see [Lessons In Electric Circuits](https://www.ibiblio.org/kuphaldt/electricCircuits/DC/index.html) for a complete background in DC and AC electronics.